# Add JavaScript code to an existing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna add a function to an existing JavaScript event :

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="2048" accesskey="S" title="Rechercher..." id="ctl00_ctl42_g_c33cc49a_f2b3_4d8f_9da7_c43b759a91ea_csr_sbox" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" onkeypress="if (Srch.U.isEnterKey(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) { $getClientControl(this).search(this.value);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event); }" onkeydown="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.activateDefaultQuerySuggestionBehavior();" onfocus="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.hidePrompt();ctl.setBorder(true);" onblur="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.showPrompt();ctl.setBorder(false);" class="ms-textLarge ms-srch-sbLarge-fullWidth">
```

I wanna add this function to the event `onkeydown`:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#k=") > -1) { 
    $("#reset").show();
}
```

Comment: Then use `addEventListener` and add another event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use less intrusive and more readable way of writing js using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
var element = document.querySelector( ".ms-srch-sbLarge-fullWidth" );
element.addEventListener( "keydown", function(){
  var ctl = $getClientControl(this);
  ctl.activateDefaultQuerySuggestionBehavior();
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("#k=") > -1) { 
    $("#reset").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: it work from the console, but when i add the script to my page it retrieve me an error : Accueil.aspx:630 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @ysfibm it looks like your script is being executed before your element has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript** `Element.addEventlistener()`

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //excute some 1
  console.log("first event fired");
}, false);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //excute some 2
  console.log("appended event fired in the same time");
}, false);
```

```html
<button id='button'>click</button>
```

**JQuery** `$("selector").on();`

```js
$("#button").on("click",function(){
console.log("first call");
});

$("#button").on("click",function(){
console.log("and appended event called in the same time");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button'>click</button>
```

Comment: it work from the console, but when i add the script to my page it retrieve me an error : Accueil.aspx:630 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null